# How to find rows between other rows w/ID then add class

Tags: jquery, html-table, rows

I'm stuck with my table. I need create toggle rows function, but I have no idea how to find sub rows in table. Can someone  help me?

1. I have table with many rows > 500
2. All Rows have class="row-1,row-2.....row-600 etc"
3. And all main rows also have class="parent"

Between each "parent" rows I have 6 rows,
so I need for toggle/collapse purposes find all (sub)rows between parent rows. and add class with id like in previous parent row.

For example:
parent have  class="row-1 parent"
all sub must have - class="child-row-1"

**default table**

```
<table id="table">
    <tr class="row-1 odd parent">
      <th class="column-1">st. 3 - 5</th>
      <th class="column-2">Profile</th>
      <th class="column-3">Purpose</th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row-2 even">
      <td class="column-1">Metal Stamp</td>
      <td class="column-2">Width</td>
      <td class="column-3">Price</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row-3 odd">
      <td class="column-1">Circle 3 - 5</td>
      <td class="column-2">28-110</td>
      <td class="column-3">21500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row-4 even">
      <td class="column-1">Circle 3 - 5</td>
      <td class="column-2">115-180</td>
      <td class="column-3">20700</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row-5 odd">
      <td class="column-1">Cube 3 - 5</td>
      <td class="column-2">63-80</td>
      <td class="column-3">21500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row-6 even">
      <td class="column-1">Cube 3 - 5</td>
      <td class="column-2">100-220</td>
      <td class="column-3">20700</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row-7 odd">
      <td class="column-1">Line 3 - 5</td>
      <td class="column-2">10-50 х 40-200</td>
      <td class="column-3">27000</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

in the end it should look like this:

```
<table id="table">
    <tr class="row-1 odd parent">
      <th class="column-1">st. 3 - 5</th>
      <th class="column-2">Profile</th>
      <th class="column-3">Purpose</th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row-2 even child-row-1">
      <td class="column-1">Metal Stamp</td>
      <td class="column-2">Width</td>
      <td class="column-3">Price</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row-3 odd child-row-1">
      <td class="column-1">Circle 3 - 5</td>
      <td class="column-2">28-110</td>
      <td class="column-3">21500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row-4 even child-row-1">
      <td class="column-1">Circle 3 - 5</td>
      <td class="column-2">115-180</td>
      <td class="column-3">20700</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row-5 odd child-row-1">
      <td class="column-1">Cube 3 - 5</td>
      <td class="column-2">63-80</td>
      <td class="column-3">21500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row-6 even child-row-1">
      <td class="column-1">Cube 3 - 5</td>
      <td class="column-2">100-220</td>
      <td class="column-3">20700</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row-7 odd child-row-1">
      <td class="column-1">Line 3 - 5</td>
      <td class="column-2">10-50 х 40-200</td>
      <td class="column-3">27000</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a [nextUntil](http://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/) method in jQuery for traversing the tree. Actually there are a bunch of methods you could use for traversing the tree and you can learn more about them [here](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/tree-traversal/).

To do this for all rows:

1. select each parent row `$('.parent').each(..)`
2. find the class name `(row-nn)`
3. add class `(child-row-nn)` to next rows until the next `.parent`.

[Update on jsf](http://jsfiddle.net/PjnA7/1/).

```
$(".parent").each(function() {
    var classes = $(this).attr('class').split(' ');
    var matches = $.grep(classes, function(item, index) {
        return /row-/.test(item);
    });
    if(matches.length == 1) {
        var parent = matches[0];
        var selector = '.' + parent;
        var childClass = 'child-' + parent;
        $(selector).nextUntil('.parent').addClass(childClass);
    }
});
```

Comment: yeah. it's work. http://jsfiddle.net/PjnA7/
but only with first parent, how i can use thistipwith all parrents?
And thanks man =)